# Junk value for Degree symbol in oracle

Tags: oracle11g, ascii, special-characters, non-ascii-characters

In my Database a column value has data with degree symbol in it.

select prop_name from tab1;
output is:
Live Steam Temperature [°C]

[image: Output from database side]

But at UI end instead of degree symbol some junk value is displayed.

[image: UI output]

Also when I checked for NLS_Parameter; I can see its "AL32UTF8"

[image]

My requirement is to display "degree symbol" correctly at UI end.
Can someone please lead me to correct findings/direction.

Comment: What character set(s) do the technologies between the database and the UI use?  What does `dump(prop_name)` show is the binary representation of the degree character?

Comment: Dump(prop_name) gives an output as "Typ=1 Len=30: 76,105,118,101,115,115,32,83,116,101,97,109,32,84,101,109,112,101,114,97,116,117,114,101,32,91,194,176,67,93"

Comment: When I query for only degree value (SELECT dump('°') FROM dual;).  I see output as "Typ=96 Len=2: 194,176"

Comment: OK.  So it looks like the character is stored correctly in Oracle.  Something between the database and whatever is displaying the character in the UI is causing the issue.  What character set(s) do the technologies between the database and the UI use?

Comment: at UI end its UTF8

Comment: Presumably, there are several layers of code between the database and the UI.  Can you describe those (i.e. you're using ODBC/JDBC/OLE DB/ODP.Net/etc to access data in a C++/Java/Python application emitting HTML that specifies the encoding in a Content-Type header/ meta element/ etc.)?  Have you done anything to debug the issue?